# How to Associate DataGridView cell location to custom object's Point member

Tags: c#, list, data-binding, datagridview, point

I have:  `List<MyOwnClass> myList` and a member of `MyOwnClass` is a `Point` object. How do I go about binding instances of `MyOwnClass` from the `List<>` to a cell location of DataGridView object based on the coordinate point values of `MyOwnClass`? I've tried using `dataGridView1.DataSource` to do the association, but that doesn't do what I want plus the ordering based from the point values would not be kept.

Example--> on a 3x3 gridview, if `myList[0]` has a `Point` value of {X=2,Y=2}, it gets placed at the bottom right corner of the table because that's where the `Point` member says it's suppose to go.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking

Comment: i think it wont work with the datasource property for different reasons. a datagridview usually binds an item to a row `row.Databounditem`. so this is a bit tricky, my idea would be to transform your list to a two dimensional list/array having the points (x/y cordiantes) as indices.